# Rearranging log expression containing division and subtraction

Tags: calculus, logarithms

I have

$$ \log\left(\frac{b\exp(a)}{1 - b\exp(a)}\right)$$

and I try to find the shortest representation. I found

$$ 0 - \log(\frac{1}{b\exp(a)} - 1)$$

and

$$ a - \log(b - \exp(a))$$

I'm wondering whether there is something better I could do. The clean setup gives me hope for more, but I fail to get anything else. I'm fine with approximations too; $a$ is negative and $b$ is positive. $a$ is potentially large, and $b \in (0, 1)$.

$a$ and $b$ are in no way related, be it in differences or products.

Comment: Is the $b$ being multiplied by $\exp(a)$? Might want to put it in front if so, to be clearer.

Comment: @ritwiksinha $exp(a)=e^a$

Comment: Don't you face a problem if $b e^a \gt 1$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Good point - I lied: $a$ is actually negative. Sorry about that.

Comment: @TheCount No, I've made that explicit.

Comment: @FooBar that was my interpretation, so you're good. it's just slightly unconventional, is all.

Answer (score 0):

You have

$ - \log(\frac{1}{\exp(a)b} - 1)$

Let $a=-c$, with $c>0$ we get

$\log\left(\frac1{\frac{\exp(c)}{b} - 1} \right)=\log\left(\frac b{\exp(c) - b} \right)=\log(b)-\log(\exp(c)-b)$

For large $c$ the term is approximately $-c=a$.